# How do I run tomcat on port 80 on Ubuntu 19.10?

Tags: ubuntu, tomcat, certbot

I need to run [Certbot](https://certbot.eff.org/lets-encrypt/ubuntuother-apache) to create a certificate for Tomcat.  Certbot requires that the web server be running on port 80.  I've changed Tomcat's server.xml to use ports 80 and 443 (instead of 8080 and 8443).  When I try to run Tomcat's startup.sh script with sudo I get

```
Neither the JAVA_HOME nor the JRE_HOME environment variable is defined
```

I've set JAVA_HOME in the /etc/profile file and rebooted but still get the same message.

I've seen solutions using authbind but I don't know if Certbot will work with authbind.

How do I get Tomcat to run on Port 80 on Ubuntu?

Comment: the port is defined in the `server.xml` config file, changing it to 80 means you would run Tomcat with root. You also can add a port forwarding on your local firewall if you don't want to run as root.

Comment: When I start Tomcat as root (sudo) it cannot find JAVA_HOME even though I've set it in /etc/profile.

Comment: usually we create a `setenv.sh` file in Tomcat's bin directory, and you can add your JAVA_HOME declaration there